# How to convert each column of df into a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, dataframe

I want to convert each column into a `dictionary` , and finally put all `dictionary` into a `list` .

```
import pandas as pd 
df= pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Dubai', 'London', 'San Fransisco'],
'temperature': [33, 12, 18,]})
print(df)
```

`Output:`

```
            city  temperature
0          Dubai           33
1         London           12
2  San Fransisco           18
```

`Expected:`

```
mylist = [
 {'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33},
 {'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12},
 {'city': 'San Fransisco', 'temperature': 18},
 ]
```

Comment: This is converting each row into a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient` parameter as `records` :

```
df.to_dict(orient = 'records')

[{'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33},
 {'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12},
 {'city': 'San Fransisco', 'temperature': 18}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you want to convert each **row** into a dictionary and
gather all of them in an array.

The answer is surprisingly short: There is a function `to_dict`,
dedicated just for this purpose.

It provides a number of ways to convert a DataFrame into a dictionary,
but what you need is *record* variant.

Use: `mylist = df.to_dict('records')`

Comment: It is exactly the same as my answer.

Comment: Probably we started (almost) at the same time, but you were quicker to answer.